# Combining a column of cell values 'C' into single cell based on condition of cells in column 'A'

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column (A) listing duplicate supervisor names related to column (C) containing individual staff names they supervise, one staff per cell.

I'd like to create a formula / Macro etc so that the cell relationship is one supervisor to one staff cell, where all staff for that supervisor are contained within that cell. Please see attached image of 'original' and 'desired outcome' to see what I'm looking to do.

I've tried a combination of CONCAT with nested IFs checking the next supervisor cell down, with = joining staff together etc. Also TEXTJOIN, ARRAY functions and pivot tables.

I'm at a point where I'm not sure what else to try. I think it must be a common manipulation in Excel.

Please see this image with original data and desired result
[image]

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

RichC

Comment: Use VBA to loop from the bottom to the top, concatenating any column that isn't one of your matching criteria and deleting newly empty rows.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, that's another good place to start from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

[image]

Formula in `A16`:

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$14,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($A$15:A15,$A$3:$A$14),0),0))
```

Formula in `B16`:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$14,MATCH(A16,$A$3:$A$14,0))
```

Formula in `C16`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($B$3:$B$14=B16,$C$3:$C$14,""))
```

Formula in `D16`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($B$3:$B$14=B16,$D$3:$D$14,""))
```

---

> **Note1:** Both the 3rd and 4th formula need to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>>

---

> **Note2**: Both column C and D need to have text wrapping ticked!

---

Prety sure this can be done through PowerQuery too.

Comment: Hey JvdV, this looks excellent - thank you! A16 and B16 evaluate correctly. However, C16 and D16 have the text wrapped and I've tried several different methods for the Array formula using Ctrl Shift Enter the and the {=...} correctly wrap the whole formula, however the #NAME? error is being returned. I thought it might be because A16 and B16 were formula's, so I copied and pasted them back as static values, still the #NAME? error.  I Googled CHAR(10) and see that's for the line endings in Win, so that's not an issue... Any thoughts? - Thanks! Rich

Comment: @Rich, I used `TEXTJOIN` since you have mentioned it in your question. `#NAME` means you don't have access to that function most likely. Please confirm you DO or DON'T have access to this function.

Comment: you're correct, sorry I didn't know that function wasn't included with my latest Excel, I thought my #NAME? error yesterday was something else within it. I have MS Professional Plus 2016 and read that TEXTJOIN was available.

Comment: @rich, unfortunately it isn't, [read this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I just tested TEXTJOIN after reading about it being available via 365 online account. - Viola, works great- so I'm going to redo your solution now on there...

Comment: @rich Excel online doesn't support array entered formulas. But I don't know about any difference if 365 online is the same or not? If you flexible in application you could also try Google sheets

Comment: It's working great in Google Sheets - Thank you so much for your help!! I can't up-vote, as this is my first post. Shall I Answer my own question as 'Solved' with a summary? - thanks man.

Comment: @rich, you can mark my post as answer by the green tick next to it. Have a look at the sites tour and help pages to see what to do when someone answers your question. Glad you got it solved.